# Variable is not used when returning an int array - NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

NetBeans complains that the borders variable is not being used. This is the code:

```
int startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn;
int[] borders;

*some code relating to ints above*

return borders = new int[] {startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn};
```

Not sure if this is a lack in my understanding of how something works or whether it is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the `borders` variable, but never read from it.  If nobody ever reads it, a variable is considered unused.  Just do:

```
return new int[] {startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn};
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't​ doing anything with border variable, didn't assign or use it since it just return the value. And I think you dont have to init with new int[] while you assign array{....}.